# Creating AWS Lambda Triggers Programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS Lambda function that takes in and processes logs from CloudWatch Logs that are sent to specific log groups. The thing is, I may need to add more triggers as more log groups are created.  The only way I have found to create a trigger for a specific log group is to use the AWS Lambda console and the AWS CloudFront console. Is it possible to create a trigger for an AWS Lambda function programmatically? For instance, in some Java code?

Comment: Did you mean "CloudFront" console? Anyway, pretty much the entire platform is programmable via API. Read the docs for CloudWatch Events for your SDK of choice.

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us more about what you mean by "create a trigger for an AWS Lambda function programmatically". Please include details about what you are wanting to accomplish (your end-state).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one of the common ways of triggering server-less functions is using endpoints. I believe you can expose an API endpoint from the Function's console using a an **API Gateway**, and call this endpoint URL from your java code or whatever programmatic entity you wish.